# Allocating / retaining model (mvc)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am curious if the code I am using here is a good way of doing this. Basically I am creating a simple model object (in the MVC sense) by lazy instanciating it from within my ViewController. The idea being that the first time I call `[[self dataModel] doSomething];` it creates a new (or reuses an existing) object. I was specifically concerned with setting the property and correctly releasing the local alloc, any comments would be much appreciated.

```
// INTERFACE
DataModel *dataModel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) DataModel *dataModel; 

// IMPLEMENTATION
@synthesize dataModel;

// Lazy Instanciation ...
- (DataModel *)model {
    if(!dataModel) {
        DataModel *tempDataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
        [self setDataModel:tempDataModel;
        [tempDataModel release]; 
    } 
    return dataModel;
} 

// Clean up
- (void)dealloc {
[dataModel release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

OR: (although I don't really like this as it looks confusing to me)

```
// Lazy Instanciation ...
- (DataModel *)model {
    if(!dataModel) {
        [self setDataModel:[[DataModel alloc] init]];
        [dataModel release];
    } 
    return dataModel;
}
```

gary.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better, and fairly standard and proper.  The second form is general bad form.  Because it's completely unclear the object you `init` is the same one that you `release`.  It's always best to think like this:

```
instiate object
do something with object
release object
```

In this case "do something with object" happens to be assigning it to a different instance variable.  But it really doesn't matter what you do there, the pattern holds true.  It's entirely up to the `setDataModel:` method what happens to the object afterward.

Personally though, I prefer the `autorelease` for most of these cases.  Simply because you have to think about it far less.

```
DataModel *tempDataModel = [[[DataModel alloc] init] autorelease];
[self setDataModel:tempDataModel];
```

So the easier pattern to remember is:

```
instantiate and autorelease object
do something with object
```

But this is a matter of taste, and many prefer the explicit `release`.

Comment: Hi, where possible I have been trying (as a rule of thumb) to avoid using autorelease. But I can see your point it does make the method a lot simpler, plus there will only ever be one so any overhead is minimal anyways. Much appreciated.

Comment: `release` is "better" than `autorelease` because it's more likely to free memory sooner.  But in my experience, `autorelease` leads to _far_ fewer bugs and prevents a lot of the super hard to debug pain associated with memory management issues.  This is because you can balance the init and release right in the same place and it's very easy to tell if it's not balanced.  And as long as your objects are not huge bundle of data, `autorelease` is not going to cause much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is clearer, although the effect is the same. Note, however, that if the idea of making `dataModel` a property and using the accessor's `retain` mechanism is to keep that all in one place the direct use of the `dataModel` ivar is breaking that encapsulation.

Actually, there seems to be a bit of a mix-up between this `model` method and the `dataModel` property. It would be better to restructure things so that everything is in the `dataModel` accessor itself, avoiding this slightly awkward redirect:

```
- (DataModel*) dataModel
{
    if ( ! dataModel )
    {
        // direct ivar access is legit inside the accessor itself
        // (at least, I would say so -- no doubt others will disagree!)
        dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    }

    return dataModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider overriding the dataModel synthesized getter. Otherwise, it could be a bit confusing with both the dataModel getter and the model messages.

I think you could override your synthesized getter like this:

```
- (DataModel *)dataModel {
    if(!dataModel) {
        dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    } 
    return dataModel;
}
```